# How to to detect if a gluon app is closed on mobile platforms

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

I have Gluon AfterburnerFX app and would like to detect when the app is closed either from the tasks  by the user or by the OS of the mobile (Android/IOS) automatically (after sometime when the app is not in use)

The stop() method seems to be executed only for desktop app and not on the mobile platform.

End goal is to keep the Gluon application running all the time.